# What is the lower bound of $\frac12(\frac{a}{x_1}-\frac{bx_1}{x_n})$, where $x_k=\sin^2\frac{k\pi}{2(n+1)}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> What is the lower bound of
> $$\frac12\left(\frac{a}{x_1} - \frac{bx_1}{x_n}\right)$$
> where $x_k=\sin^2\frac{k\pi}{2(n+1)}, a > b > 0$?

I tried to simplify the expression as
$$\begin{align}
\frac{a x_n - b (x_1)^2}{2 x_1 x_n} &= \frac{2a \sin^2\frac{n\pi}{2(n+1)} - 2b \sin^4\frac{\pi}{2(n+1)}}{4\sin^2\frac{n \pi}{2(n+1)}\sin^2\frac{\pi}{2(n+1)}} \\[6pt]
&= \frac{2a \cos^2\frac{\pi}{2(n+1)} - 2b \sin^4\frac{\pi}{2(n+1)}}{\sin^2\frac{n\pi}{n+1}}\end{align}$$

Then I let $n = 1$ to simplify the whole thing into $a - \frac12b$. Is there a higher lower bound?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: can you simplify $x_1+x_n$?

Comment: Yes, but as the original expression becomes $a/(2x_1) + b/2 - b/(2x_n)$, can we further simplify and make a higher lower bound?

Comment: As $n$ increases, $x_1$ decreases towards zero.  Does the expression increase or decrease?

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ positive ?

Comment: yes; I forgot to mention this